# In an Azure WebRole where is %AppData% redirected to?

Tags: iis, azure

I'm logging using NLog in an Azure WebRole to the "%appdata%" folder.

But when I RDP into the Azure VM I can't find my log file anywhere -- %appdata% opens a folder the user I'm RDPed in as -- where is the appdata folder I should be looking for?

Not sure if it's relevant, but, I acquire the folder in C# via `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` both in WebRole.cs and in Global.asax.cs. -- My service is set to run elevated (in the .csdef file).

It looks like my Site's application pool is being run by Network Service, and I think his %appdata% folder could be located at `D:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming`, but I don't see my logging folder getting created there or any of my log files.

Is this the correct folder and it's a permissions issue (and how would I tell?), or is it getting redirected somewhere else (and if so, where)?

Answer (score -1):

Please check in C -> User ->  Username ->

Ensure hidden files are enabled in folder view settings.